# C++ setfill() Crash

Tags: c++, crash, codeblocks, borland-c++

I'm sorry if this has been addressed before, but after hours of searching I came up with nothing. I am new enough at C++ that perhaps I just wasn't searching for the right phrases.

Essentially, here's a rundown of my problem.

I'm working my way through a textbook (Object Oriented Programming in C++, Fourth Edition) by myself (no instructor). At the end of chapter 2 there is an exercise (#8) asking the student to take this code:

```
long pop1=2425785, pop2=47, pop3=9761;
cout << setw(8) << "LOCATION" << setw(12)
     << "POPULATION" << endl
     << setw(8) << "Portcity" << setw(12) << pop1 << endl
     << setw(8) << "Hightown" << setw(12) << pop2 << endl
     << setw(8) << "Lowville" << setw(12) << pop3 << endl;
```

And add in periods between the town names and their populations using setfill(). I already have the required #include  at the top for setw(), and as far as I have found setfill() is in the same header.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 with (at the suggestion of the textbook) the Borland C++ compiler (the free 5.5 version). Right away something seemed off when Code::Blocks failed to auto-format the setfill() function in the way that it had formatted the setw() function (in green). The compiler doesn't even give a warning, but when I run the program I get a nasty "chapter2objectives.exe has stopped working" dialog box. Every single time I run this thing, it crashes.

**IMPORTANT NEW UPDATE**
I just installed Orwell Dev C++ and compiled this code there. With the exception of it not recognizing the `system("PAUSE")` command (says system is undefined), the code compiled and ran without crashing. This is either a Code::Blocks issue, or some other strange thing.

I've been studying C++ on my own for a few weeks now. I've already run through a C++ for Dummies book, I've got 14 years as an amateur JavaScript code-tinkerer, and I have no idea what is going on here.

I've tried several things. Obviously setfill() takes a char value; I've been doing it like this:

```
long pop1=2425785, pop2=47, pop3=9761;
cout << setw(8) << "LOCATION" << setw(12)
     << "POPULATION" << endl
     << setw(8) << "Portcity" << setfill('.') << setw(12) << pop1 << endl
     << setw(8) << "Hightown" << setfill('.') << setw(12) << pop2 << endl
     << setw(8) << "Lowville" << setfill('.') << setw(12) << pop3 << endl;
```

I've also tried moving the setfill() around, a lot. I most often saw it online preceding the setw(), but I've tried it both before and after, I've tried it just once and multiple times, I've tried it as a standalone "cout << setfill('.');" line before the execution, I even tried an alternative fill() method that I found on a reference site.... It seems that no matter where I put the setfill() command, at the exact point where the fill character should first appear in the output the whole program crashes.

I've considered stepping through with the debugger, but I doubt I'll see anything that would tip *me* off to a problem. I'm guessing (and hoping) it's an issue that's way over my head, like a bug in Code::Blocks, or a quirk in the Borland compiler (although the author says that all of the code in the book compiled and ran just fine with the Borland compiler).

Anyone who has any suggestions at all that I might not have tried, please let me know! I hate having something like this that just plain won't work!

**EDIT**
Here's the SSCCE (new to me, thanks!):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ex8()
{
    cout << "Now we'll be printing a table from an example, but with a little something extra thrown in." << endl;

    //#8 Rewrite the WIDTH program so that the characters on each line between the location name and the population number are filled in with periods instead of spaces.
    //Doesn't require anything that isn't already listed with #include (uses IOMANIP, I think)
    //For some strange reason setfill() is broken here.
    cout << "Begin exercise 8:" << endl;
    long pop1=2425785, pop2=47, pop3=9761;
    cout << setw(8) << "LOCATION" << setw(12)
         << "POPULATION" << endl
         << setw(8) << "Portcity" << setfill('.') << setw(12) << pop1 << endl
         << setw(8) << "Hightown" << setfill('.') << setw(12) << pop2 << endl
         << setw(8) << "Lowville" << setfill('.') << setw(12) << pop3 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int iEx;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter an exercise number to execute (0 to exit): ";
        cin >> iEx;
        cout << endl;
        if (iEx == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        switch (iEx)
        {
        case 8:
            ex8();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "No such exercise has been written yet." << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Exiting program." << endl;
    //wait until user is ready before terminating program
    //to allow the user to see the program results
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for this setup is that for each exercise I am allowing the user (me, really) to pick which one to view the output/interaction for, then return to the main loop to view another (or exit).

**EDIT 2**
This code runs without crashing for everyone but me. If the community wants, I will remove this question and just accept that there is an unexplained bug on my system. I would much prefer some help tracking down what could be causing it (right now it's just a cout << setfill() problem, but what if I experience future crashes due to some underlying problem>). But I understand that some bugs are impossible to track down.

I am a little confused by the gentleman (or woman) who immediately stated that the problem can't be with Code::Blocks. The program is auto-formatting all of the proper built in functions *except* the setfill() command. And it's the setfill() command that is crashing my system. I don't know on what grounds you can rule out Code::Blocks so quickly, but since I am new at all of this I am going to have to just accept it.

Comment: The code you show is 100% not the reason of the crash. Post a complete compilable example, please. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41b9311c576245fb).

Comment: That said, Borland 5.5 is...ancient. Code::Blocks comes with GCC, why not use that?

Comment: Added the SSCCE - thanks for introducing that to me, jrok.

Comment: T.C. - I switched to the GCC and it still crashes. I do use GCC for my regular projects, but the textbook projects recommend the Borland compiler, so I'm using it to ensure that any mistakes are mine, not the compilers.

Comment: How do I participate in the discussion on the moderation? I feel that CodeBlocks is part of the problem because the setfill() command is not being properly recognized. Plus, they called it a minor problem but I feel that minor problems still should be understood.

Comment: Did you actually include `<ctype>` and not `<cctype>`? Because other than that, this seems to [work just fine](http://ideone.com/7a77L6).

Comment: I do not know the difference between those, but having cctype didn't fix it for me. Still crashing.

Comment: `<ctype>` is not a standard header. It's weird that it even compiled with that.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I'm thinking this is some kind of weird fluke. I can't get it to not crash on my system, and everyone else is doing fine. Should I delete the question, skip the exercise (it looks like I got the code mostly right), and pretend it works fine? Is it even worth pursuing this? I appreciate your help, T.C.

Comment: OK, I just made a copy of the code on my Windows computer, compiled it with my GCC, and it works fine. So it's nothing wrong with your code. I suspect that it's probably something broken with your compiler setup. It may be worth doing a clean install of the Code Blocks-GCC package (after removing the previous compilers and Code Blocks from your computer), and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, especially when learning a language, you should use a new, modern compiler, not one more than a decade old. If the code in the book doesn't compile under a modern compiler, then that's a problem with the book, not the compiler.

Comment: Nope. Fresh installation (didn't even bother with Borland this time) and it's still crashing the moment the first fill character is supposed to be printed in. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: But how would I know if the problem is with the book or the compiler or me? My logic tells me that if I'm using the compiler they compiled things with and everything worked for them, then I should do the same and any problems at that point would be mine and not the compiler's. Of course, I guess the same isn't holding true for this problem... I find this very discouraging.

Comment: @T.C. It's a Code::Blocks problem. I installed Orwell Dev C++ and it compiled and printed properly (no crash). I added the codeblocks tag back onto this issue. I hope that it doesn't get removed this time. I'd still be interested in finding a solution for Code::Blocks on my system, but perhaps it would be better handled as a bug report to the Code::Blocks guys. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: @brianhaddad - Dev-C++ and Code::Blocks are not C++ compilers.  They are integrated development environments.  You need to note the version of the compiler and compiler tools that are used, and then work from there (gcc version).  An IDE is not responsible for compiler bugs (if this is a compiler bug).  For example, the compiler version would be something like `gcc 4.7` or something like that.

Comment: @brianhaddad I just tried Code::Blocks on my system with GCC and it works just fine (as PaulMcKenzie points out, Code::Blocks itself is just an IDE and not responsible for compilation). Personally, my current hypothesis is that this might be because of some sort of weird header/library mish-mash due to configuration problems.

Comment: @brianhaddad - I believe it is some sort of conflict between the headers used for compilation, and the runtime that is being used.  There is hardly a chance a compiler as widely used as gcc can get something simple as a `setfill` function call wrong, unless the object code produced by the compiler and runtime library are out of sync.

Comment: I'm _kind of_ tracking some of what you guys are saying, @PaulMcKenzie & T.C., but I'm afraid it's not very useful for me in trying to fix the problem. I do understand the difference between the IDE and the compiler, but since I used the same version of GCC with both IDEs I can only assume that the problem is occurring as a result of the way in which the IDE communicates with the compiler. Like I said, Code::Blocks did not correctly identify setfill() as a proper function. The compiler didn't complain about it, but Code::Blocks must be somehow responsible (from my perspective, anyway).